# Datacontext of ControlTemplates

Tags: wpf, binding, datacontext, controltemplate

How does a ControlTemplate handle the datacontext?

Using the the follow Template

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ToolbarButtonHover" TargetType="Button">
    <Grid Name="backgroundGrid">
        <Image Source="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Img}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"></Image>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.ToolSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="Unlink">
            <Setter TargetName="backgroundGrid" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

with the control

```
<Button Content="Button" 
        Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ToolbarButtonHover}" 
        Height="24" Width="24" Background="Red">
    <Button.Resources>
        <ImageSource x:Key="Img">Resources/Icons/toolSelect.png</ImageSource>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

But this does not make the background red. I have verifyed that the value of the ToolbarViewModel Property `ToolSelected` is in fact Unlink by having a `<Label Content="{Binding ToolSelected}"/>` next to the controll.  So i believe the problem is that the template does not use the correct `DataContext`, but I'm not sure of this. That's why i ask you for help.

The Control lies in a custom usercontrol, and the ToolbarViewModel is set as context for all of it, like so.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:ToolboxView/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Comment: What is the type of ToolSelected ?

Comment: `ControlTemplate` overrides all of the object's properties. therefore, once you've set a `ControlTemplate` to your button, giving it a `Background` has no meaning ...

Comment: He doesn't "give a Background" to the Button but to the Grid inside the ControlTemplate. Plus if you use TemplateBinding, giving a Background to a re-templated Control is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing `RelativeSource` from `DataTrigger.Binding` then it should work in current `DataContext`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ToolSelected}" Value="Unlink">
   <Setter TargetName="backgroundGrid" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</DataTrigger>
```